# Razor DropDown with "Add New" choice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop down that builds a list using related data from an SQL table (with linq and MVC5, ASP.NET etc).  Currently my drop down is like this in the contoller:

```
ViewData["TeamList"] = new SelectList(db.Players.Select(p => p.Team).Distinct(), TeamFilter);
```

and the view looks like this:

```
<span class="pull-right searchDD" id="TeamDD">Team: @Html.DropDownList("TeamList", "-All-")</span>
```

I want to add a choice at the top of the list that says "Add New" and that choice will call my "Create" Action for the Team controller.  HOw would I do this?  Is it possible?

I thought perhaps I could build a list with the DB data, then add an ADD NEW option to the start of this list like :

```
List<SelectItemList> TeamList = new List<selectItemList>();
TeamList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Add NEW", Value = "99" });
foreach(var team in db.Players.Select(p => p.Team).Distinct())
{ TeamList.Add{ Text = team.Name, Value= team.id };}
```

THEN use Jquery to nmonitor for a value of 99 being selected on the Dropdown, and load a Create Controller Action from there, but that seems super tedious and code-intensive.

Is there an easier way?  If not, how do I load a Controller/Action from JQUERY (I can SO search that too)....

Comment: That approach sounds reasonable to me. I would not use 99. I would go with a negative number or 0 or null to avoid possible collisions with the valid player ids(if you use the id's as the option value)

Comment: Your own suggestion is about the only way to add the additional, but why not just have a link or button adjacent to the dropdown for adding a new item?

Comment: Indeed, UX wise you really should use a button. You can even use the [Bootstrap input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) feature to make it "attached" to your dropdown. You should ask whether a user will find it intuitive to have to click a `<select>` option to perform an action--I think the answer is no in most cases :)

Comment: Going to use input groups.  I feel like I've seen drop down lists before though where there was a "Add New" choice at the top of the list....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would advise not to. You're asking to do something like this:

[image: dropdown]

First, how will you know a user selected that option since it's the first one? You'll need to add yet another option above it (blank, or a placeholder).

Second, this is not a great design--it's not intuitive to a user, they have to click the dropdown to even see they can add a new team. What if they don't click it and therefore had no idea they could add a team?

Third, you said it best yourself, it's adds a lot of unnecessary code! Bunch of JS to handle something HTML can do for this natively.

Let's switch to [using a Bootstrap input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) and make it easier for them:

[image: Input group]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Teams</label>

      <span class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Team 1</option>
          <option>Team 2</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action('Create', 'Team')">Add Team</a>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm still not 100% sure I like this either since it kinda implies you're adding the selected team to something. I might just opt to separate the button from the `<select>` element afterall. Up to you!

Notice how I'm also leveraging the ASP.NET MVC `HtmlHelper` `@Url.Action()` to provide a link to your create team action/controller.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/4pxp7r3w/

Comment: I would have had it default to ---Select--, I still will, so I dont think the Add New button will be confusing...i'll see how it looks when im done.  Also nice side note on Url.Action, did not know its usage, was always using Html.ActionLink.